# using loop to fitting the target in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a function that finds the target quantity by the input target profit, I try to use a loop to fit each unit it fits the target profit. The program runs fine but I want to confirm my logic is correct or not in the following program

> Note

- 1-1000 $1 per unit
- 1001-5000 $2 per unit
- 5001 and above $5 per unit

finally, I have marked two places in the following program and I don't know why it overflow.

```
double computeMinQuan(double target) {
    int tarquan = 0;
    double tarpro = 0;
    do {
        if (target <= 1000) {
            tarquan++;
            tarpro = tarquan * 1;
        }
        else if (target <= 9000) {
            tarquan++;
            tarpro = 1000 + tarquan * 2; // overflow 
        }
        else {
            tarquan++;
            tarpro = 9000 + tarquan * 5;  //overflow
        }
    } while (tarpro < target);
    return tarquan;
}
```

Comment: If you want to make sure your code is running as intended, you might want to create software tests for your code.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get your meaning...

Comment: The logic is broken because loop ends after you had assigned value that doesn't fit the target value

Comment: A simple test example and rewrite your code. https://godbolt.org/z/E9Wxnaf4h

Comment: In your "Note", are the ranges for the target profit or target quantity? I presume quantity, given the style of question it is, but that means your `if`/`else` is based on the wrong variable.